# adding date and time to the image using imagemagick via PHP?

Tags: php, imagemagick

I'm trying to add a date and time to an image using `imagemagick and php`.

I can make this work but for some reason, it only adds the date to the image so no time is being added to the image at all!

Example: what I am looking for is to add this to the image:

```
12/04/2019 12:56:08
```

This is my simple code:

```
///get the dateand time using php here//

date_default_timezone_set("Europe/London");
$datetime = date('d/m/Y h:i:s a');

////and add it to the image///

exec("/usr/bin/convert source.png -pointsize 24 -fill red -undercolor '#000000' -gravity SouthWest -annotate +10+10 ".$datetime." result.png);
```

The result looks like this:
[image]

could someone please advice on this issue?

Thanks in advance.

**FIXED THE ISSUE BY REMOVING -undercolor '#000000'**

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are getting 10 symbols. like you provide with --annotate

Comment: i tried this: +0+90 but this only changes the position of the date on the image NOT the amount of symbols/characters.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
date_default_timezone_set("Europe/London");
$datetime = date('d/m/Y h:i:s a');
exec("/usr/bin/convert source.png -pointsize 24 -fill red -undercolor '#000000' -gravity SouthWest -annotate +0+5 ".$datetime." result.png);
```

Comment: look at 'annotate'

Answer (score 0):

For a start you do not have a closing " after result.png - forum post error?

This worked for me on a windows localhost:

```
exec("convert source.jpg -pointsize 24 -fill red -undercolor '#000000' -gravity SouthWest -annotate +10+10 \"$datetime\" result.png");
```